# Mongo delete and insert vs update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongo version 3.0 db and java driver. I have a collection 100,000+ entries. Each day there will be approx 500 updates and approx 500 inserts which should be done in a batch. I will get the updated documents with old fields plus some new ones which I have to store. I dont know which are the feilds are newly added also for each field I am maintaining a summary statistic. Since I dont know what were the changes I will have to fetch the records which already exist to see the difference between updated ones and new ones to appropriately set the summary statistics.So I wanted inputs regarding how this can be done efficiently.

Should I delete the existing records and insert again or should I update the 500 records. And should I consider doing 1000 upsers if it has potential advantages.

Example UseCase
initial record contains: f=[185, 75, 186]. I will get the update request as  f=[185, 75, 186, 1, 2, 3]  for the same record. Also the summary statistics mentioned above store the counts of the ids in f. So the counts for 1,2,3 will be increased and for 185, 75, 186 will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Upserts are used to add a document if it does not exist. So if you're expecting new documents then yes, set `{upsert: true}`.

In order to update your statistics I think the easiest way is to redo the statistics if you were doing it in `mongo` (e.g. using the aggregation framework). If you index your documents properly it should be fine. I assume that your statistics update is an offline operation.

If you weren't doing the statistics in `mongo` then you can add another `collection` where you can save the updates along with the old fields (of course you update your current collection too) so you will know which documents have changed during the day. At the end of the day you can just remove this temporary/log `collection` once you've extracted the needed information.

Comment: Thank you! And about delete and insert vs update which one would you pick?

Comment: You should `update` your records since it is a single operation where `delete` and `insert` are two. But I am not sure what you mean by "plus some new ones which I have to store". Could you give an example?

Comment: So lets say my record has fields a,b,c. Next day a new field might be added it will have fields a,b,c,d. None of the old field values will be removed so a,b,c,d cant be removed. But potentially more fields can be added.

Comment: What do you have in your fields? Is it a huge hashmap?

Comment: well actually the data is like this f=[185, 75, 186] I am actually storing storing a set in db. And to this new ids like 1,2,3 etc can be added to make it f=[185, 75, 186,1,2,3] I dont think it will grow beyond size 10 in most cases.

Comment: So you're not adding new fields, but you're `$push`-ing new elements into your arrays?

Comment: I guess that would be a more appropriate way of putting it.

Comment: OK. Then just save either the updates in a new document or both arrays, whichever you need. Btw you can use `$addToSet` to add new elements into your sets.

Comment: Well actually I need to store the full updated documents. But it would be helpful if there could be some efficient way to tell what is the difference between the record at hand and one in the db. Like in the db the record will be  f=[185, 75, 186] and I will get a request on my api to store f=[185, 75, 186,1,2,3]

Comment: If you save your updates and the old values in a different collection than that's it. If you're not satisfied with this answer please add a real example to your question showing the update and what you're expecting to get.

Comment: Thanks! I will express it more clearly. So I have  f=[185, 75, 186] in db for a record. I will get a request to store(update) f=[185, 75, 186,1,2,3]. Additionally I am maintaing the counts of each of the elements in the set. So that I can find out what % of records contain id 1, what percentage contain id2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Mongo maintains every change log using oplog.rs capped collection in local db. We are creating a tailable cursor on oplog.rs on timestamp basis and each change in db / collection are streamed thru. Believe this is the best way to identify changes in mongo. One can certainly drop no interest document changes. 
Further read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-oplog

Comment: Thank you but I cant opt for a capped collection because I don't know my db size. But for updating around 500 records what will you pick delete+insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to redo the statistics if you were doing it in mongo (e.g. using the aggregation framework). If you index [upsers](https://upserscomlogin.xyz/) documents properly it should be fine. I assume that your statistics update is an offline operation.